# Write PDF file bytes to a file with Perl?

Tags: perl, file, pdf, soap, file-io

I'm reading a PDF file into an array of bytes `byte[]` and sending this to a Perl SOAP::Lite web service. Once the Perl service receives this array of bytes, I'd like to write them to a file (with a PDF extension of course).

How can I achieve this?  All the examples I can dig up assume that I'd like to begin with opening a file, reading, then writing...but what if only have the raw data to work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think array of bytes is good use of perl data structures, you would waste a lot of memory this way. Just use string for file contents and write it into binary file (`:raw` setting in `open`):

```
my $pdf_data = 'contents of PDF ...';
open my $ofh, '>:raw', 'output.pdf'
    or die "Could not write: $!";
print {$ofh} $pdf_data;
close $ofh;
```

Comment: This code does create a file, however, the file appears to be getting corrupted somehow. Ideas?

Comment: @YourMomzThaBomb - make sure you use binary mode on all sides (sending and receiving) to prevent unwanted transformation of newlines. Use some binary diff tool to determine differences.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? My Perl is a little rusty.

```
  open(OUTFILE,">>output.pdf"); 
  binmode OUTFILE;
  foreach my $byte (@bytes){
    print OUTFILE $byte;
  }
  close(OUTFILE);
```